# Inverter with capacitor and Zener diode?

Tags: capacitor, inverter, zener

Why author of this circuit used capacitor and Zener diode (see the part marked in red below)?

[image]

Comment: I'll be honest about the three BJTs that make up the drivers for each transformer limb - never seen anything like that before - any ideas anyone?

Comment: @Andyaka My theory is that it's a drafting misteak (sic). The TIP122 darlingtons are supposed to drive the two 3055s in parallel with 0.1R emitter ballast resistors on each. Here's another such ['design'](http://inverter-circuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/500W-power-inverter-circuit-diagram.jpg)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany who asked your opinion LOL Yeah you're probably right but i was hoping to learn something new! Now I am dissapointed double LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 12V is intended to come from a vehicle electrical system, the originator may have been concerned about voltage changes and transients on the supply. It will regulate the voltage so the oscillator is not too affected by changes in the supply (for example, from the noise this circuit generates or from the difference between a vehicle with engine running or not). A 9V zener is suggested online.

Note that the [CD4047](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~herniter/Data_Sheets/CD4047BC.pdf) operation is very stable with **slow** changes in supply voltage (see curve E below), but changes in supply voltage *during a cycle* can cause problems. This is similar to the supply voltage (in) sensitivity of an LM555.

[image]

The output stage is pretty strange- the transistors will have very high drop (2-3V) and will not share current equally. Maybe Q3/Q4 and Q5/Q6 were intended to be in parallel (with individual emitter ballast resistors).

Comment: Agree, this circuit works but isn't very efficient. It looks like a design from the 1980s ! ;-) These days I would use some NMOSFETs to replace each set of 3 NPNs. But in the 1980 no such FETs existed or were very expensive.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Maybe even mid-1970s.

Comment: The earliest reference I can find to the CD4047 is from the mid-70's indeed. This was a RCA chip it seems. The original datasheet is nowhere to be found online.

Answer (score 5):

That is there to provide a simple regulated supply voltage for IC1.

It will help the frequency remain constant with changes in input voltage.

Comment: You have to mention that R1, ZD1 and C1 are making a simple regulated voltage. In Question topic R1 is neglected.